# Unable to access database irs_990 for table irs_990_reporting Dataprep Google Cloud

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

I am having problems with Google DataPrep when I am trying to create a table. There is a message "Unable to access database irs_990 for table irs_990_reporting".

You, guys, can see all the steps here.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u5rFyg7nMv4YJ_u_ASjpmVdkusJARTN2gCtBj8zr4T0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

---

Thanks for all your answers, but I still have this problem. I tried all your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. I have just one project, one flow, one dataset and one job. I created a new flow, to make it more clear.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CU6CU_-plQ9Id1etj5nLbJ6iKSVPQURZISk6YYohAM0/edit?usp=sharing

[Here in this image, you can see some permissions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puGac.png)

It is alive! It is alive! It is alive!

Will's answer solve this issue, I don't understand why it happened, so if you guys have some answer to specify, it would be perfect.

Thanks, Will

Comment: It is alive! It is alive! It is alive!

Will's answer solve this issue, I don't understand why it happened, so if you guys have some answer to specify, it would be perfect.

Thanks, Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same (similar?) issue. I was able to fix it by creating an empty table in destination BQ dataset. That seemed to allow the dataprep to then create its own table.

I found this solution by looking at the big query logs in stackdriver.

Comment: It is alive! It is alive! It is alive!
Thanks, man, it is working, actually I don't understand why it happened, but fortunately, it is working!
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the original "Create-CSV", and after "Add Publish Action" and do it again.

I suppose it's a bug.

Comment: Hello Leonardo. Thanks for your answer.  I've tried this option,but it is not working. I have just one project, one flow, one dataset and one job.

I created a new flow, to make it more clear. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CU6CU_-plQ9Id1etj5nLbJ6iKSVPQURZISk6YYohAM0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dataprep can't currently read datasets from a different project, including public projects. But there is a way to work around this:

1. In your own project, create a new view - pointing to the desired dataset.
2. Direct Dataprep to the view you created.

[image]

Then the view will be available in Dataprep:

[image]

And you'll be ready to play:

[image]

Comment: Hello Felipe Hoffa. Thanks for your answer
Well, actually I'm not reading datasets from different projects.
I have just one project, one flow, one dataset and one job.

I created a new flow, to make it more clear. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CU6CU_-plQ9Id1etj5nLbJ6iKSVPQURZISk6YYohAM0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!